# draw rectangle in java beginner

Tags: java, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to modify a current method for drawing a square:

```
length = 100;

            int index = 1;

            while (index <= 4) {
                    tParam.forward(length);
                    tParam.turn(90);
                    index++;
            }
```

Basically can't figure out what to change `tParam.turn();` to. Help?

Comment: Assuming that the value isn't relative to the current direction, you might try `90 * index`...this might require you to turn first then draw though

Comment: Rectangles have 90 degree angles too.

Comment: Please add more information to your question including what your code currently does, what you're trying to make it do, where you're stuck, and any other background information that could help us understand it better.

Comment: @Hovercraft - don't tell me you never had a turtle in your younger days?

Comment: What's it doing now? How is turn defined -- what are the units?

Comment: @DavidWallace: nope, they didn't have them when I learned Turbo-PASCAL. I really want the OP though to think through his problem for us a bit though.

Comment: (Not everyone is familiar with the turtle robot and tail-dragging drawing.)

Comment: I'm using a turtle to call the method. It's currently creating a square and I'm just trying to modify the square method to create a rectangle

Comment: Then you need 2 length variables, don't you, one for each pair of sides?

Comment: @keshlam we're currently not using other units aside from pixels for pen width. I've been trying to go off a unit circle to approximate degrees but nothing I plug in seems to be working

Comment: here's the start of the code:   public static void drawRectangle(Turtle tParam, int length) { where would I insert the 2nd length variable? would just be another tParam.forward(length);?

Comment: Fantastic.  Now imagine that you have a pen attached to your tail and you want to draw a rectangle.  Where do you go?  How far do you walk before you turn to the side?

Comment: My guess would be 90 forward, turn, forward 180, penDown, forward 90, turn, forward 180, penUp, forward 90? I think that would create a rectangle. Not sure how to articulate that into a method with a while loop

Comment: It's an interesting guess.  Why don't you forget about the loop for the moment, just code up that series of turtle commands, and see what it draws?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
int height = 100; //the height of the rectangle
int width = 200; //the width of the rectangle
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) //repeat the following twice
{
    tParam.forward(height); //go forward the height of the rectangle
    tParam.turn(90); //turn 90 degrees
    tParam.forward(width); //go forward the width of the rectangle
    tParam.turn(90); //turn 90 degrees
} //end loop
```

Comment: I ended up figuring out a couple days ago but this really helps thanks!